# Asp.net url routing parameter issue

Tags: asp.net, url, url-routing

I'm using URL routing In ASP.net Web form and send some parameter to page via RouteData.
but when parameter somethings like `name.cd`, page redirect to the Not found!
I think this problem occurred because parameter contains `.cd`(`cd` in command means change directory)

My code in Global.asax:
`routes.MapPageRoute("G", "group/{name}", "~/page1.aspx")`

Example page url:
`example.com/group/x.cd`

How can fixed this problem without change group name(`.cd`) and url schema(`group/groupname`)?

Comment: Check out this link and see if it helps you: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-integrated-pipeline

Comment: thanks, but how to disable wildcard checking in url routing?